# Need to change CircleBorder color when choosing from multiple colors in a gridview

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

In the following image, a yellow circle:

[image: yellow circle]

When I click on it, a Gridview appears with a set of colored circles:

[image: colored circles]

I would like the color of the circle in the first image to be changed to the color clicked from the group of circles.

Currently clicking on any color does not make any change

And here's the code:

```
class NewCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewCounterState createState() => _NewCounterState();
}
class _NewCounterState extends State<NewCounter> {
  final FocusNode textNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode numberNode = FocusNode();
  TextStyle labelStyle;
  TextStyle numberStyle;
  List<Color> colorsList = [
    Color(0xFFF44236),
    Color(0xFFEA1E63),
    Color(0xFF9C28B1),
    Color(0xFF673BB7),
    Color(0xFF3F51B5),
    Color(0xFF2196F3),
    Color(0xFF03A9F5),
    Color(0xFF00BCD5),
    Color(0xFF009788),
    Color(0xFF4CB050),
    Color(0xFF8BC24A),
    Color(0xFFCDDC39),
    Color(0xFFFFEB3C),
    Color(0xFFFEC107),
    Color(0xFFFF9700),
    Color(0xFFFE5722),
    Color(0xFF795547),
    Color(0xFF9E9E9E),
    Color(0xFF607D8B),
    Color(0xFF000000),
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textNode.addListener(onFocusChange);
  }
  void onFocusChange() {
    setState(() {
      labelStyle = textNode.hasFocus ? TextStyle(color: kMainColor) : null;
    });
    setState(() {
      numberStyle = numberNode.hasFocus ? TextStyle(color: kMainColor) : null;
    });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    textNode.dispose();
    numberNode.dispose();
    textNode.removeListener(onFocusChange);
    super.dispose();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: kMainColor,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    PageTransition(
                      type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: CountNumbering(),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
            title: Text(
              'New Counter',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/floppy-disk.png',
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                  }),
            ],
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15.0, top: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 0.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        focusNode: textNode,
                        cursorColor: kMainColor,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
                          labelText: 'Name',
                          labelStyle: labelStyle,
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Color(0xFF5A5A5A),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: kMainColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 15.0, top: 0.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        focusNode: numberNode,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                        ],
                        cursorColor: kMainColor,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
                          labelText: 'Start value',
                          labelStyle: numberStyle,
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Color(0xFF5A5A5A),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: kMainColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 33.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Select a Color',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            spreadRadius: 2,
                            blurRadius: 2,
                            // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: GridView.builder(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: colorsList.length,
                                    gridDelegate:
                                        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                                            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                                            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                                            crossAxisCount: 5),
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      var color = colorsList[index];
                                      return MaterialButton(
                                          elevation: 0,
                                          color: color,
                                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                            setState(() {
                                            });
                                          });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                        },
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        color: kMainColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: you have to define a color, and initilaize it with kMainColor, and affect it to your circle

Comment: you have to initialize the kMainColor and change it in the setState on click

Comment: Can you provide a sample code please?